# raspberry pi4, hostapd is only working in hw_mode=a (5Ghz)

Tags: raspberry-pi4, hostapd

I got a raspberry pi 4 with:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
```

When I run hostapd in hw_mode=a, everything works fine, I can see my AP and connect to it from remote devices, but when I want to use hw_mode=g or hw_mode=b, it starts without errors but I AP is not not visible, but several times I saw it was up, but only for a few seconds.

My hostapd.conf (tried with different options)

```
country_code=US
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211w=0
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=RD
hw_mode=a
channel=36
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Log for hw_mode=a

```
# sudo hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf 
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Using driver-based roaming
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1018 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=1 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x55783b0d30 (device SME)
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55783b0d30 match=04
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55783b0d30 match=0501
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55783b0d30 match=0504
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55783b0d30 match=06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55783b0d30 match=08
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55783b0d30 match=09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55783b0d30 match=0a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55783b0d30 match=11
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55783b0d30 match=7f
nl80211: Enable Probe Request reporting nl_preq=0x55783b20f0
nl80211: Register frame type=0x40 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_PROBE_REQ) nl_handle=0x55783b20f0 match=
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 3 (ifidx_reason -1)
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 3(-1)
phy: phy0
BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Previous country code US, new country code US 
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=US (DFS-FCC)
nl80211: 2400-2472 @ 40 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 5150-5250 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm
nl80211: 5250-5350 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5470-5730 @ 160 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5730-5850 @ 80 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 57240-71000 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=36 freq=5180 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=40 freq=5200 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=44 freq=5220 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=48 freq=5240 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=149 freq=5745 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=153 freq=5765 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=157 freq=5785 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=161 freq=5805 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=165 freq=5825 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11a  Channel: 36  Frequency: 5180 MHz
DFS 0 channels required radar detection
nl80211: Set freq 5180 (ht_enabled=0, vht_enabled=0, bandwidth=20 MHz, cf1=5180 MHz, cf2=0 MHz)
  * freq=5180
  * vht_enabled=0
  * ht_enabled=0
  * channel_type=0
RATE[0] rate=60 flags=0x1
RATE[1] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[2] rate=120 flags=0x1
RATE[3] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[4] rate=240 flags=0x1
RATE[5] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=540 flags=0x0
hostapd_setup_bss(hapd=0x55783b0120 (wlan0), first=1)
wlan0: Flushing old station entries
nl80211: flush -> DEL_STATION wlan0 (all)
nl80211: Station flush failed: ret=-14 (Bad address)
wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
wlan0: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlan0 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> 0 (Success)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=0)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=2)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=3)
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr dc:a6:32:c5:cf:d9 and ssid "RD"
Deriving WPA PSK based on passphrase
SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=2):
     52 44                                             RD              
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=8): [REMOVED]
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
GMK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
Key Counter - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: Delay group state machine start until Beacon frames have been configured
nl80211: Set beacon (beacon_set=0)
nl80211: Beacon head - hexdump(len=53): 80 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff dc a6 32 c5 cf d9 dc a6 32 c5 cf d9 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 00 11 00 00 02 52 44 01 08 8c 12 98 24 b0 48 60 6c 03 01 24
nl80211: Beacon tail - hexdump(len=40): 07 0a 55 53 20 24 04 17 95 05 1e 00 30 14 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 02 00 00 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: ifindex=3
nl80211: beacon_int=100
nl80211: dtim_period=2
nl80211: ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=2):
     52 44                                             RD              
  * beacon_int=100
  * dtim_period=2
nl80211: hidden SSID not in use
nl80211: privacy=1
nl80211: auth_algs=0x1
nl80211: wpa_version=0x2
nl80211: key_mgmt_suites=0x2
nl80211: pairwise_ciphers=0x10
nl80211: group_cipher=0x10
nl80211: beacon_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: proberesp_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: assocresp_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
WPA: Start group state machine to set initial keys
WPA: group state machine entering state GTK_INIT (VLAN-ID 0)
Get randomness: len=16 entropy=0
GTK - hexdump(len=16): [REMOVED]
WPA: group state machine entering state SETKEYSDONE (VLAN-ID 0)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=3 addr=0x557778c9b0 key_idx=1 set_tx=1 seq_len=0 key_len=16
nl80211: KEY_DATA - hexdump(len=16): [REMOVED]
   broadcast key
nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->1 (UP)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 0.
Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 1.
Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 2.
Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 3.
wlan0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
wlan0: AP-ENABLED 
wlan0: Setup of interface done.
ctrl_iface not configured!
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 operstate=2 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 operstate=6 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
VLAN: RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
VLAN: vlan_newlink(wlan0)
```

Log for hw_mode=g (channel=3)

```
sudo hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf 
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Using driver-based roaming
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1018 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=1 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x55ca4b8d30 (device SME)
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55ca4b8d30 match=04
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55ca4b8d30 match=0501
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55ca4b8d30 match=0504
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55ca4b8d30 match=06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55ca4b8d30 match=08
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55ca4b8d30 match=09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55ca4b8d30 match=0a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55ca4b8d30 match=11
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55ca4b8d30 match=7f
nl80211: Enable Probe Request reporting nl_preq=0x55ca4ba0f0
nl80211: Register frame type=0x40 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_PROBE_REQ) nl_handle=0x55ca4ba0f0 match=
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 3 (ifidx_reason -1)
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 3(-1)
phy: phy0
BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Previous country code US, new country code US 
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=US (DFS-FCC)
nl80211: 2400-2472 @ 40 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 5150-5250 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm
nl80211: 5250-5350 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5470-5730 @ 160 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5730-5850 @ 80 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 57240-71000 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=36 freq=5180 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=40 freq=5200 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=44 freq=5220 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=48 freq=5240 MHz max_tx_power=23 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=149 freq=5745 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=153 freq=5765 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=157 freq=5785 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=161 freq=5805 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=165 freq=5825 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 3  Frequency: 2422 MHz
DFS 0 channels required radar detection
nl80211: Set freq 2422 (ht_enabled=0, vht_enabled=0, bandwidth=20 MHz, cf1=2422 MHz, cf2=0 MHz)
  * freq=2422
  * vht_enabled=0
  * ht_enabled=0
  * channel_type=0
RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x1
RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x1
RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x1
RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x1
RATE[4] rate=60 flags=0x0
RATE[5] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=120 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[8] rate=240 flags=0x0
RATE[9] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[10] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[11] rate=540 flags=0x0
hostapd_setup_bss(hapd=0x55ca4b8120 (wlan0), first=1)
wlan0: Flushing old station entries
nl80211: flush -> DEL_STATION wlan0 (all)
nl80211: Station flush failed: ret=-14 (Bad address)
wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
wlan0: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlan0 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> 0 (Success)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=0)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=2)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=3)
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr dc:a6:32:c5:cf:d9 and ssid "RD"
Deriving WPA PSK based on passphrase
SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=2):
     52 44                                             RD              
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=8): [REMOVED]
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
GMK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
Key Counter - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: Delay group state machine start until Beacon frames have been configured
nl80211: Set beacon (beacon_set=0)
nl80211: Beacon head - hexdump(len=53): 80 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff dc a6 32 c5 cf d9 dc a6 32 c5 cf d9 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 00 11 04 00 02 52 44 01 08 82 84 8b 96 0c 12 18 24 03 01 03
nl80211: Beacon tail - hexdump(len=45): 07 06 55 53 20 01 0b 1e 2a 01 04 32 04 30 48 60 6c 30 14 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 02 00 00 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: ifindex=3
nl80211: beacon_int=100
nl80211: dtim_period=2
nl80211: ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=2):
     52 44                                             RD              
  * beacon_int=100
  * dtim_period=2
nl80211: hidden SSID not in use
nl80211: privacy=1
nl80211: auth_algs=0x1
nl80211: wpa_version=0x2
nl80211: key_mgmt_suites=0x2
nl80211: pairwise_ciphers=0x10
nl80211: group_cipher=0x10
nl80211: beacon_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: proberesp_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: assocresp_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
WPA: Start group state machine to set initial keys
WPA: group state machine entering state GTK_INIT (VLAN-ID 0)
Get randomness: len=16 entropy=0
GTK - hexdump(len=16): [REMOVED]
WPA: group state machine entering state SETKEYSDONE (VLAN-ID 0)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=3 addr=0x558d7f09b0 key_idx=1 set_tx=1 seq_len=0 key_len=16
nl80211: KEY_DATA - hexdump(len=16): [REMOVED]
   broadcast key
nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->1 (UP)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 0.
Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 1.
Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 2.
Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 3.
wlan0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
wlan0: AP-ENABLED 
wlan0: Setup of interface done.
ctrl_iface not configured!
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 operstate=2 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 operstate=6 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
VLAN: RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
VLAN: vlan_newlink(wlan0)
```

My hostpad version is 2.6, but I also tried 2.4, 2.5, 2.7 and 2.8, no difference.

Could anyone suggest what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, it seems to be in firmware BOOTPART/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb, after replacing it with fresh version from Ubuntu 21.04, wifi access point works correctly in any hw_mode.